# How did Mathew Bevan acquire hacking skill without belonging to military or national agencies?

Tags: computers

This my post may be inappropriate since math may be irrelevant in this topic.

I've read [this article of wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathew_Bevan) of the hacker called Mathew Bevan.

Seemingly the ariticle has not specified how Bevan acquired the skills of hacking which led him to penetrate into the system of the air-force-base.

I always wonder how nominant hackers has acquired the hacking-skills.

For instance in math, we can acquire the skills of calculus-stuff doing exercises of problems in textbooks. But how with penetrating into a military-system?

By the way I know that some pentest-os let us to learn some ethical-hacking-skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had plenty of free time. Bulletin Board Systems / Forums and the magazines Phrack & 2600 gave good jumping off points.

Mostly trial and error and swapping knowledge with other phreakers and hackers. Practice, Practice, Practice :-)